# Upload image to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have been looking at solutions but don't know where I am doing it wrong. But I am doing it for the first time.

I have a class Students

```
class Students
{

    public Image photo { get; set; }


    public bool AddStudent(Students _student)
    {
        Settings mySettings = new Settings();

        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(mySettings.StudentsConnectionString);
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into students (firstname, lastname, dob, allergic, allergydetails, memo, address, photo) " +
                            "Values (" +
                            "'" + @FirstName + "'," +
                            "'" + @LastName + "'," +
                            "'" + @Dob + "'," +
                            "'" + @isAllergic + "'," +
                            "'" + @AllergyDetails + "'," +
                            "'" + @Memo + "'," +
                            "'" + @photo + "'," +
                            "'" + @Address + "')";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", _student.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", _student.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dob", _student.Dob);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@isAllergic", _student.isAllergic);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AllergyDetails", _student.AllergyDetails);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Memo", _student.Memo);


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", _student.photo);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", _student.Address);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
            cmd = null;
        }
    }
```

Now I pass the property values from my form like this.

```
  private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Students myStudent = new Students();

            myStudent.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            myStudent.LastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
            myStudent.Dob = dtPicker1.Value;
            myStudent.Memo = txtMemo.Text.Trim();
            myStudent.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();

            myStudent.photo = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            // Insert New Record
            if (myStudent.AddStudent(myStudent))
                MessageBox.Show("Student Added Successfully");


        }
```

I am getting the following error

> No mapping exists from DbType System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known
>   SqlCeType.

But I don't know why I am not succedding. Any Suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you need to convert your image to a byte[], it can then be stored in an image data type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx

Comment: From my experience, its been a while doing this... you should use a BLOB field in the DB, and stream the image to byte array, before putting it in the BLOB field.

Comment: You don't understand, my question is different. I am keeping the photo in a class instance first and then uploading it to the db. In the instance, I don't have features like openfiledialog.filename etc.

Comment: It sure is possible to upload images to a MS Database, but make sure that the images are of low quality(thumbnails), because it will slow down your database. Store the images on a server and put the paths to the images as a string in your database to load your images.

Comment: Good comment. Thanks I will keep that in mind. But will it make any different If I am using SQL Compact CE ? I am now getting exception The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = binary ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try converting the image to `Byte[]` array and then save.

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Students myStudent = new Students();
    ...
    ...
    // change the student photo to byte array e.g. 
    // public byte[] Photo {get;set;}
    myStudent.photo = imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName));
    ...
    ...
    // Insert New Record
    if (myStudent.AddStudent(myStudent))
    MessageBox.Show("Student Added Successfully");
 }

 // convert image to byte array
 public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
 {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return  ms.ToArray();
 }

//Byte array to photo
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Note: your DataType in database must be `image` type

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but it isn't working at all. I am getting this error message on cmd.executenonQuery(). The error is this " The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = image ]"

Comment: What is the datatype of photo in DB?

Answer (score 1):

Chech out this link..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25956/Sending-Receiving-PictureBox-Image-in-C-To-From-Mi

Do you really have to store the image in database?

You can achieve this task with much less effort if you just store the image in a folder(have it uploaded to your application) and then store the path of that image in the database in "Varchar" field.
I've worked more on websites but basics should be the same I think....

Comment: Yeah I believe that is something i should do now. Its a Desktop Based Stand alone application that uses Local Database. So I will be better off just storing the location of that image. Or may be Copy that Image to my defined folder so evenif the user deletes the image from that location, we will have a copy