# Insert blob in table without bulk load permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, blob, image-uploading

I am trying to insert an image into a table in SQL Server using OPENROWSET and the bulk command.

However, I do not have permission to `use the bulk load statement.`.

I have been using SqlLobEditor for a while now, but sadly my trial has run out and I cannot upload my blobs anymore. The system in itself is quite legacy, and I cannot get the permissions I need to be able to do this with T-SQL.

Are there any free alternatives to SqlLobEditor I can use that does the same? For some reason that worked, but using T-SQL doesn't, so I don't quite understand what SqlLobEditor does that's different.

I've also thought about writing some web client way of doing it, but as of now I'm not allowed to do that either...

Comment: You can write your own C# program to do this without bulk insert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014465/upload-image-to-sql-database?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: This would be a good task for SSIS. There is a pretty thorough step by step guide here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/14/sql-server-ssis-and-how-to-load-binary-large-objects-or-blobs-notes-from-the-field-080/